# Confused with what statistical test to choose

Tags: inference

Hoping someone can help me determine what statistical test to use if I am examining the relationship between categorical demographic variables and the number of times an individual goes backpacking.

4 Nominal/Categorical Independent Variables (age, 4 levels of race, 2 levels of occupation, 2 levels of sex)

1 Ratio Dependent Variable (number of times backpacking - 0-10)

1 purposive Sample (e.g., 100 individuals age 18-55 years from a specific organization)

Comment: Your outcome is a count so you may be interested in something like a poisson regression or a negative binomial regression.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Demetri in the comment you could use Poisson Regression, if you happen to be using R for your analysis you can learn how to do this following these tutorials: [UCLA tutorial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/) or [data-quest tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-poisson-regression-in-r/). Hope this helps!